# Loop through table on click for each row without knowing any of the records

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to loop through a table each time a button is clicked. Currently I had set it up to increment a counter and then just get the id match of the counter number. But this is not a good way of doing this as I found out the ID column in the table is not consistent. After ID 2 it skips to 5 so it goes 1-2-5-6-7 etc. So when the counter is at 3 it fails because Row with ID 3 does not exists.

Is there a way I could increment through without knowing the ID. Just get all the row data?

```
        private void nextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Setup Connection to access db
        string cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\braithwaite.mdb";

        //declare Connection, command and other related objects
        OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

            //open connection
            conGet.Open();
            //String correctAnswer;

            cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

            cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SAM_IG_Questions WHERE ID = @counter";

            cmdGet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@counter", counter.Text);

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();

            questionNumber.Text = reader["QuestionName"].ToString();
            iqquestion.Text = reader["Description"].ToString();
            if (reader["Option1"] != DBNull.Value) { radioButton1.Text = reader["Option1"].ToString(); radioButton1.Show(); }
            else { radioButton1.Hide(); }
            if (reader["Option2"] != DBNull.Value) { radioButton2.Text = reader["Option2"].ToString(); radioButton2.Show(); }
            else { radioButton2.Hide(); }
            if (reader["Option3"] != DBNull.Value) { radioButton3.Text = reader["Option3"].ToString(); radioButton3.Show(); }
            else { radioButton3.Hide(); }
            if (reader["Option4"] != DBNull.Value) { radioButton4.Text = reader["Option4"].ToString(); radioButton4.Show(); }
            else { radioButton4.Hide(); }
            correctanswer.Text = reader["Answere"].ToString();
            instructions.Text = reader["Instructions"].ToString();
            correctInstructions.Text = reader["Instructions"].ToString();

            //questionNumber = 0;

            conGet.Close();
            //End Connection to access db
            panel1.Visible = true;
            iqresult.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: If you were using SQL Server then you could use ROW_NUMBER() to number the rows being returned sequentially. And if you don't specify an ORDER BY clause then there is no order guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Leave there `WHERE` clause out.

```
cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SAM_IG_Questions";
```

Then loop through your rows with

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    //handle row data  
}
```

Edit: example how to use OleDbDataReader.Reader method: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Edit2: Now I get what you want to achieve, you're not trying to loop though a table but rather you want to get next row. In that case you need to select single row, store id of loaded row and ask for the next row on click. The code should look something like this:

```
cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SAM_IG_Questions WHERE ID > @id" ORDER BY ID;
cmdGet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@counter", this.lastId);
...
reader.Read();
this.lastId = (int) reader["ID"]; 

questionNumber.Text = reader["QuestionName"].ToString();
...
// read other data as usual
```

`this.lastId` should be initialized to -1 in constructor

Comment: Can you show an example of handling the data? How do I step through using this I tried iqquestion.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Description"]); I tried reader.GetString(1); After the first click to the next question it shows the last question then each click just shows the last question again... Do I still need to use a counter and increment the GetString(#)

Comment: @Bowenac - To make this work you need to do two things. First, add `ORDER BY ID` to the query to ensure that the results are returned in the correct order. Second, use a loop to read (`Reader.Read()`) the first `Counter` rows. That should leave the `reader` on the correct row so that you can access the column values.

Comment: @Bowenac I've updated my answer. I think that you're trying to do is get the next row

Comment: Thank you this looks like it would work. Not sure if you noticed my answer below but I ended up using a datagridview and load all the data on load. Then access the correct row through that. Doesn't that seem like it would be a better solution just curious. As then I am not doing a query on each click. It seems fast just not sure which would be the best option.

Comment: @Bowenac Depends on a use case, but it's usually a good idea to minimize the DB round-trips unless you're dealing with a huge amount of data (somewhere in 100 thousand area and more) or your data is often updated and you always need up to date data. So yeah DataGridView seems like a reasonable solution. Just a tip, use column names instead of indices if you can. `Cells["ID"]` instead of `Cells[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try: `cmdGet.CommandText = "select * from ( SELECT *, Row_Number() over ( order by Id ) as RN FROM SAM_IG_Questions ) as Ellen where RN = @counter";`

This will generate a column of sequential numbers (`RN`) that are in the same order as the `Id` column values, then select only the row where the row number matches your counter.

To test this in SQL Server:

```
-- Create a sample table.
declare @SAM_IG_Questions as Table ( Id Int, Option1 Int, Option2 Int );
-- Load some sample data and display it.
insert into @SAM_IG_Questions ( Id, Option1, Option2 ) values
  ( 1, 0, 0 ), ( 2, 1, 0 ), ( 5, 1, 1 ), ( 6, 0, 1 ), ( 7, -1, -1 );
select * from @SAM_IG_Questions;
-- Display data with row numbers.
select *, Row_Number() over ( order by Id ) as RN FROM @SAM_IG_Questions;
-- Get a specific row by row number.
declare @Counter as Int = 3; -- Third row reading in order of increasing   Id   values.
select * from
  ( select *, Row_Number() over ( order by Id ) as RN FROM @SAM_IG_Questions ) as Ellen
  where RN = @Counter;
```

Comment: I get a debug error from Row_Number() over ( order by Id  it doesn't know what that is. Also what is Ellen?

Comment: This is the error Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Row_Number() over ( order by ID )'.

Comment: @Bowenac - `Ellen` is a placeholder required by the TSQL syntax. If you prefer to use `Roger`, that's fine. I've added a TSQL demonstration to the answer. None of this will work if you are using Access. If your question was tagged with the database and version ... .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using datagridview and this seems to be quicker as well since I am not running a query on each click event.

```
    private int count = 1;
    private void nextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int test = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
        //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString() + test);

        if (count < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
        {
            int question = count + 1;
            questionNumber.Text = "Q" + question;
            iqquestion.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[3].Value != DBNull.Value) { radioButton1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[3].Value.ToString(); radioButton1.Show(); }
            else { radioButton1.Hide(); }
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[4].Value != DBNull.Value) { radioButton2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[4].Value.ToString(); radioButton2.Show(); }
            else { radioButton2.Hide(); }
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[5].Value != DBNull.Value) { radioButton3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[5].Value.ToString(); radioButton3.Show(); }
            else { radioButton3.Hide(); }
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[6].Value != DBNull.Value) { radioButton4.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[6].Value.ToString(); radioButton4.Show(); }
            else { radioButton4.Hide(); }
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[7].Value != DBNull.Value) { radioButton5.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[7].Value.ToString(); radioButton5.Show(); }
            else { radioButton5.Hide(); }
            correctanswer.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            instructions.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            correctInstructions.Text = instructions.Text;
            count++;
        }
        if (count == (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
        {
            var homeform = new Home();
            homeform.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

            panel1.Visible = true;
            iqresult.Visible = false;
    }
```